# How to remove the blue highlight of a button once pressed when u remove original border?

Tags: html, css

I don't want the blue border when you click on a button that doesn't have its original border, here is the HTML:

```
<div id="buttonholder" style="border 1px solid black">
    <button id="previous">&lt; Previous round</button>
    <button id="next">Next round &gt;</button>
    <button id="current">&gt; Current round&lt;</button>

    <div style="font-size: 0;">
        <form id="inputfield" name="inputfield">
            <input type="inputfield" value="Search for round here...">
            <input type="button" value="Go">
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="displayround">
        1/38
    </div></button>
</div>
```

If I need to post the entire CSS let me know, just added it in the html to make it short.

Answer (score 11):

In Chrome at least, the blue border is a result of the `focus` pseudo-class, not `active`.

Set `outline: none` in that selector and it will go away:

```
button:focus, input[type="button"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its caused by most browsers default styling of the `outline` property on the `:active` state

```
button:active, input[type="button"]:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Thought this would work but it makes the blue appear still? :/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little vague, but try "outline: none;"

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is use of the :visited in your css.

If it's an anchor tag, try

```
a:visited {
   text-decoration: none;
   border: none;
   color: black; /* change to your desired color */
}
```